# Problems retrieving payment method

Tags: checkout, admin

We're using a custom extension that allows users to create quotes, in the more traditional sense of a quote. They put together an order, go through checkout, and save the order to their account without paying, and allowing them to order it at a later date with a set pricing. Why? I don't know exactly, but that's what it does. Now, when a user created a quote, it would decrement the stock, on the frontend that was easily resolved by having it check the

```
$quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()
```

attribute. This is throwing errors in the backend though:

```
Order saving error: Can not retrieve payment method instance
```

I cannot access the getMethodInstance attribute at all from the backend checkout, so I cannot test to see if the "payment method" is a quote. I'm not too sure what I should even be troubuleshooting on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a result of the quote not having a quote_payment associated.

Usually this is due to an exception raised by the payment module or the gateway returned an error.

Try the following, as a test:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(/* Your quote's id here */);

if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/checkmo/active')){
  Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('payment/checkmo/active', true);
}
$quote->getPayment()->setMethod('checkmo');
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

After this, the following should work:

`$quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()`

The reasoning is that we've created a payment of type `checkmo` against the quote, and now the method instance should be available.

Comment: While this does in fact give me access to the method, regardless of what the selected payment method is set as during the orders creation getCode() and getMethod()/getMethodInstance() all return String: 'checkmo', rather than the set payment method. As far as creating the object so that I can check it sure, but only in a very non-functional way.

Comment: Okay, so the test as recommended did prove that a payment method was not attached. At this point you may not have a full payment method attached to your quote so you will need to attach a proper payment method with the gateway of your choice. If you recommend a gateway I can provide some sample code to help you debug it.

Comment: The problem was almost entirely my lack of experience with Magento, after inspecting the 'adminhtml/session_quote' object for a payment method, I found that it was indeed there.