# Onepage Checkout - Get selected payment method

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I'm trying to get user's current selected payment method, in onepage checkout page. I tried the following

```
$paymentMethod = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
```

but the payment method returned is not correct. Actually it's a method that's not even activated in my store (check/money order).

Why is this happening and how can I get the correct value?

Comment: where are you want this value?

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getPayment()->getMethod()

Comment: @AmitBera that gives "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::getPayment()"

Comment: it  mistake Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod()  and let me where r u want to fetch this value...

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/problems-retrieving-payment-method

Comment: Where do you try to get this? Are you sure that the user has already chosen the payment method at this stage?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
$session  = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

$quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id );

$paymentcode = $quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but I'm still getting 'checkmo' as the selected payment method code.

Comment: Try disabling `checkmo` method from backend.

Comment: Please don't use the "load fixes all" remedy, without thorough explanation why. It results in extra queries and negatively affects performance.

Comment: @HungryDB 'checkmo' is for 'Check - Money Order' which is already disabled

Answer (score 2):

If customer already selected a payment method in checkout/onepage (or another checkout) and saved it to quote, to get current payment instance:

```
$methodInstance = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment();
```

Now, if you need only the current payment method code:

```
$methodCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
```